# Extracting formulas from WIkipedia pages - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia-api

I am extracting wikipedia pages and writing them in a file using python. Currently am doing this : 
code snippet :

```
keyWords = ["kinetic energy", "gravitational force"]

for word in keyWords:
    topic = wikipedia.page(word)
    text = topic.content
    print text
```

But the content has bad formatting when it displays formulas. 
For eg :

```
F = ma becomes something like :

F

   m

a
```

Can you help me figure out how can I have the mathematical formulas cleanly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no LaTeX in the Wikipedia pages grabbed by the Wikipedia module. In order to extract all the equations from a Wikipedia page you can take advantage of the BeautifulSoup package.

```
import wikipedia
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

topic = wikipedia.page('kinetic energy')
equations = BeautifulSoup(topic.html()).find_all('annotation')
```

You can then extract the source of any given equation via

```
equations[0].text
#'{\\displaystyle {\\vec {F}}=m{\\vec {a}}}'
```

or

```
equations[0].text.split('{\\displaystyle ')[1][:-1]
#'{\\vec {F}}=m{\\vec {a}}'
```

though this is still not an entirely useful format. You should also note that there tends to be a lot of "one letter" equations that arise from references to a variable, so this might not be the best technique. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for this approach. I will try this! I want to create text files of around 2000 topics and query them for information retrieval.